# NumPy vectorization with integration

Tags: numpy, vectorization, quad

I have a vector [image] and wish to make another vector of the same length whose k-th component is

[image]

The question is: how can we vectorize this for speed? NumPy vectorize()  is actually a for loop, so it doesn't count.

Veedrac pointed out that "[There is no way to apply a pure Python function to every element of a NumPy array without calling it that many times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23849233)". Since I'm using NumPy functions rather than "pure Python" ones, I suppose it's possible to vectorize, but I don't know how.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
ws = 2 * np.random.random(10) - 1
n  = len(ws)
integrals = np.empty(n)

def f(x, w):
    if w < 0: return np.abs(x * w)
    else:     return np.exp(x) * w

def temp(x): return np.array([f(x, w) for w in ws]).sum()

def integrand(x, w): return f(x, w) * np.log(temp(x))

## Python for loop
for k in range(n):
    integrals[k] = quad(integrand, -1, 1, args = ws[k])[0]

## NumPy vectorize
integrals = np.vectorize(quad)(integrand, -1, 1, args = ws)[0]
```

On a side note, is a Cython for loop always faster than NumPy  vectorization?

Comment: Another possible speedup, which you didn't ask for, but, which is woth mentioning is parallelization with openmp.

Comment: @Dschoni Yes. f(x, w) is defined in my code.

Comment: No, I mean F(x,w) as in F'=f

Comment: Just asking, because if you don't have to integrate numerically but analytically, stuff is WAY faster.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function `quad` executes an *adaptive* algorithm, which means the computations it performs depend on the specific thing being integrated. This cannot be vectorized in principle.

In your case, a `for` loop of length 10 is a non-issue. If the program  takes long, it's because integration takes long, not because you have a `for` loop.

When you absolutely need to vectorize integration (not in the example above), use a non-adaptive method, with the understanding that precision may suffer. These can be directly applied to a 2D NumPy array obtained by evaluating all of your functions on some regularly spaced 1D array (a `linspace`). You'll have to choose the linspace yourself since the methods aren't adaptive.

- [numpy.trapz](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) is the simplest and least precise
- [scipy.integrate.simps](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html) is equally easy to use and more precise (Simpson's rule requires an odd number of samples, but the method works around having an even number, too).
- [scipy.integrate.romb](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.romb.html#scipy.integrate.romb) is in principle of higher accuracy than Simpson (for smooth data) but it requires the number of samples to be `2**n+1` for some integer `n`.

Comment: [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy)'s [`integrate_adaptive`](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy/blob/master/quadpy/line_segment/tools.py#L45) is adaptive _and_ vectorized. (Disclaimer: I'm the author.) Refinement takes place if the error estimate for [_any_](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy/blob/master/quadpy/line_segment/tools.py#L76) of the entries in the vector is too large. This is less efficient than adaptive integration for each of the vector elements separately, but generally the vectorization makes more than up for it.

Answer (score 2):

`@zaq's` answer focusing on `quad` is spot on.  So I'll look at some other aspects of the problem.

In recent https://stackoverflow.com/a/41205930/901925 I argue that `vectorize` is of most value when you need to apply the full broadcasting mechanism to a function that only takes scalar values.  Your `quad` qualifies as taking scalar inputs.  But you are only iterating on one array, `ws`.  The `x` that is passed on to your functions is generated by `quad` itself.  `quad` and `integrand` are still Python functions, even if they use `numpy` operations.

`cython` improves low level iteration, stuff that it can convert to `C` code.   Your primary iteration is at a high level, calling an imported function, `quad`.  Cython can't touch or rewrite that.

You might be able to speed up `integrand` (and on down) with `cython`, but first focus on getting the most speed from that with regular `numpy` code.

```
def f(x, w):
    if w < 0: return np.abs(x * w)
    else:     return np.exp(x) * w
```

With `if w<0` `w` must be scalar.  Can it be written so it works with an array `w`?  If so, then

```
 np.array([f(x, w) for w in ws]).sum()
```

could be rewritten as

```
 fn(x, ws).sum()
```

Alternatively, since both `x` and `w` are scalar, you might get a bit of speed improvement by using `math.exp` etc instead of `np.exp`.  Same for `log` and `abs`.

I'd try to write `f(x,w)` so it takes arrays for both `x` and `w`, returning a 2d result.  If so, then `temp` and `integrand` would also work with arrays.  Since `quad` feeds a scalar `x`, that may not help here, but with other integrators it could make a big difference.

If `f(x,w)` can be evaluated on a regular nx10 grid of `x=np.linspace(-1,1,n)` and `ws`, then an integral (of sorts) just requires a couple of summations over that space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) for fully vectorized computation. You'll have to adapt your function to allow for vector inputs first, but that is done rather easily:

```py
import numpy as np
import quadpy

np.random.seed(0)
ws = 2 * np.random.random(10) - 1


def f(x):
    out = np.empty((len(ws), *x.shape))
    out0 = np.abs(np.multiply.outer(ws, x))
    out1 = np.multiply.outer(ws, np.exp(x))
    out[ws < 0] = out0[ws < 0]
    out[ws >= 0] = out1[ws >= 0]
    return out


def integrand(x):
    return f(x) * np.log(np.sum(f(x), axis=0))


val, err = quadpy.quad(integrand, -1, +1, epsabs=1.0e-10)
print(val)
```

```
[0.3266534  1.44001826 0.68767868 0.30035222 0.18011948 0.97630376
 0.14724906 2.62169217 3.10276876 0.27499376]
```