# How to define a vectorized function which incorporates scipy integrate?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, numerical-integration

I have a function which looks like this:

```
def test(x,q0):
    q = q0/(1+x**2)
    h_func = lambda t: 1/sp.cosh(t)**2
    fun = lambda t: sp.log(1+q*h_func(t))
    return spi.quad(fun,-sp.inf,sp.inf)[0]
```

How do I make it vectorized so that it can accept `x` as an array? Right now, it shows

> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

I can achieve this in Matlab using

`integral(fun,-Inf,Inf,'ArrayValued',true)`,

but is there a Python equivalent of the `'ArrayValued',true` in Matlab?

Comment: What's the expected output? Say, if you called it with `test(np.array([1, 2, 3]), 0.1)` what should be the result?

Comment: it should give `array([ 0.0983764 ,  0.03973614,  0.01993369])`, which is just what we get if we apply the function to each of the element in `np.array([1,2,3])` separately.

Comment: The quick and dirty solution would be to do `test = np.vectorize(test)` but note that `vectorize` is not a performance feature :)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't just want to iterate through `x` within `test`? I doubt that it would be much slower than calling a function that does the iteration for you (if such a function would exist).

Comment: I want to do some data fitting with a function that looks similar to the one in example, and it seems that `sp.optimize.curve_fit` requires a function which accepts vector `z`, so I want the function to be vectorizable. I can add a for loop inside the function, but it seems to me that this is quite slow, especially when it is evaluated many times during the optimization. I can think of pre-evaluating the function over a 2d array for various `t` and `z`, and do the numerical integration myself using `trapz` or `simps` , but I wonder if a better method exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NumPy vectorization with integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223186/numpy-vectorization-with-integration)